# to train fasttext with pretrained data of GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin

Tags: fasttext

i want to train fasttext with the pretrained data of GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin in python.

i have tried this

fastTet_model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('path/to/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')

but this code give me a error

NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported